# Aggregating deletions and insertion indexes efficiently

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have a type that is used for updating the UI. This is the pseudo code for it.

```
{
  Item[] AllItems;
  long[] ItemsRemovedFromPreviousUpdateByIndex;
  long[] ItemsAddedToPreviousUpdateByIndex;
}
```

These update are quite frequent, and contain a lot of data. We want to aggregate these instances and deliver just one update every 200ms to the UI. There may be 20 or 30 updates per 200ms window.

My question is whether there's a good way to aggregate the indices. I can't think of a way to do it without allocating a lot of memory.

Comment: Are the longs representing the indices that were removed/added, or some other data? (I assume something else, otherwise they would be int arrays)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to store that data in a pair of `int`s, `long`s, or `BigInteger`s, depending on how many indices you have.

First think about doing something like this:

```
boolean[] added = new boolean[allItems.length];
boolean[] removed = new boolean[allItems.length];
```

Where the booleans are true if and only if the item at the corresponding index was not added/removed.

But then rather than doing this, I would try to represent the boolean array as a long, or if needed, a BigInteger. Since, tttfftfftf --> 1110010010 --> 914.

You can look into methods for flipping a single bit from 0 to 1, and if it's already a 1, leave it alone. You'll need to be clever in your init case, since you're starting out with all 0s (which is 0) and the first index might be large, so you would need to go from `0` to `10...0` in one step, which is just `1 << n`. From there you are just flipping single bits, and possibly shifting, if you need to flip the bit at `j > n` where `n` was from the init-case mentioned above.

Keep in mind that you will always need to know the length of the `allItems` array  at each reset, since `00001001` is the same as `1001`, so if the length is 8, you should interpret `1001` as `00001001`.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  That solution does involve allocating quite a lot of memory for each update.  The hard part is mapping the indices over multiple updates.  e.g. if update 2 deletes items at index 10000-10004, any subsequent update will need to know to add 4 t the removed index for indices >10000.

Comment: @JamesL if you delete at index 10004, then you would flip the 10004th bit and leave it flipped for all subsequent updates before re-init. You would not add 4, because 4 is the “third” bit, and if we are removing indices above 10000 then the third bit is untouched.

Comment: Let me put it another way.  The first update is a new snapshot, adding 100,000 items.  The second update removes a single item @ 10,000.  The third update removes 10,000 again. Except it's not 10,000 with respect to the first update, it's 10,001.  The aggregated update should have both 10,000 and 10,001 in the removed items array.

Comment: I see what you mean. It's required that the array be resized at the second update? Array resizing is typically expensive. If it must be that way, then I agree you will need a more robust data structure to keep track of changes, which is costly. The obvious choice would be a hashmap or a set. What is your current best idea?

Comment: It's not essential that the array is resized.  I could always optimise that by exposing a slice.

My best idea for tracking removed items is to have a LinkedList of removed ranges, and keep a tally of total removed items at each threshold.  The details are a bit fuzzy at the moment, was just wondering whether this was a common problem.